# How to create a line that has two arrows in Cesium?

Tags: glsl, cesiumjs

Cesium has various polyline materials (PolylineArrow, PolylineDash, PolylineGlow etc.) but

I want to draw a polyline consisting of lines that has an arrow in their head and an arrow in their  center.

I think it can be done by adding GLSL code to PolylineArrowMaterial.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only one idea that I have is adding section of polyline with arrow header instead on single polyline like this :

```
 points.forEach((x, i) => {
            if (i < points.length - 1) {
                 polylines.add({
                     positions: [points[i], points[i + 1]],
                     width: 12.0,
                     material: Cesium.Material.fromType('PolylineArrow', {
                     color: new Cesium.Color.fromBytes(255, 255, 0, 185)
                     })
                });

        }
    });
```